# How to let the code run smoothly using timers and different threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, cross-thread

I'm trying to prevent the GUI from *freezing*, because of a low timer interval and too much to process in the `Timer.Tick` event handler.
I've been googling a while and I understood that I cannot update UI from any other thread other than the UI thread.

So, what about if you are using lots of controls under `Timer1.Tick`?
How can I update a Label when the data is downloaded with WebClient with a timer, you don't want to lower the interval too much and keep the UI responsive at the same time?

I receiver Cross Thread violation exceptions when I access UI elements, a ListBox1 and a RichTextBox.

What is the correct way to update the UI with a timer and/or a Thread without causing cross threat exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different ways to update UI elements from a Thread other than the UI Thread.
You can use the `InvokeRequired/Invoke()` pattern (*meh*), call the *asynchronous* `BeginInvoke()` method, [`Post()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post) to the [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext), maybe mixed with an [AsyncOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation) + [AsyncOperationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager) (solid BackGroundWorker style), use an async callback etc.

There's also the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class and its [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface.
This class provides a quite simplified way to capture the `SynchronizationContext` where the class object is created and `Post()` back to the captured execution context.
The `Progress<T>` delegate created in the UI Thread is called in that context. We just need to pass the `Progress<T>` delegate and handle the notifications we receive.
You're downloading and handling a string, so your `Progress<T>` object will be a **`Progress(Of String)`**: so, it will return a string to you.

The Timer is replaced by a Task that executes your code and also delays its actions by a Interval that you can specify, as with a Timer, here using [Task.Delay([Interval])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) between each *action*. There's a [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) that measures the time a download actually takes and *adjusts* the Delay based on the Interval specified (it's not a *precision thing*, anyway).

---

▶ In the sample code, the download Task can be started and stopped using the **`StartDownload()`** and **`StopDownload()`** methods of a helper class.
The `StopDownload()` method is awaitable, it executes the cancellation of the current tasks and disposes of the disposable objects used.

▶ I've replaced WebClient with HttpClient, it's still quite simple to use, it provides async methods that support a `CancellationToken` (though a download in progress requires *some time* to cancel, but it's handled here).

▶ A Button click initializes and starts the timed downloads and another one  stops it (but you can call the `StopDownload()` method when the Form closes, or, well, whenever you need to).

▶ The `Progress<T>` delegate is just a Lambda here: there's not much to do, just fill a ListBox and scroll a RichTextBox.
You can initialize the helper class object (it's named **`MyDownloader`**: of course you will pick another name, this one is ridiculous) and call its `StartDownload()` method, passing the `Progress<T>` object, the `Uri` and the `Interval` between each download.

```
Private downloader As MyDownloader = Nothing

Private Sub btnStartDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartDownload.Click
    Dim progress = New Progress(Of String)(
        Sub(data)
            ' We're on the UI Thread here
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Split(data, vbLf))
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        End Sub)

    Dim url As Uri = New Uri("https://SomeAddress.com")
    downloader = New MyDownloader()
    ' Download from url every 1 second and report back to the progress delegate
    downloader.StartDownload(progress, url, 1)

Private Async Sub btnStopDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopDownload.Click
    Await downloader.StopDownload()
End Sub
```

The helper class:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class MyDownloader
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Shared client As New HttpClient()
    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing
    Private interval As Integer = 0
    Private disposed As Boolean

    Public Sub StartDownload(progress As IProgress(Of String), url As Uri, intervalSeconds As Integer)
        
        interval = intervalSeconds * 1000
        Task.Run(Function() DownloadAsync(progress, url, cts.Token))
    End Sub

    Private Async Function DownloadAsync(progress As IProgress(Of String), url As Uri, token As CancellationToken) As Task
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

        Dim responseData As String = String.Empty
        Dim pattern As String = "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>"
        Dim downloadTimeWatch As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
        downloadTimeWatch.Start()
        Do
            Try
                Using response = Await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, token)
                    responseData = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    responseData = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(responseData, pattern, ""))
                End Using
                progress.Report(responseData)

                Dim delay = interval - CInt(downloadTimeWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                Await Task.Delay(If(delay <= 0, 10, delay), token)
                downloadTimeWatch.Restart()
            Catch tcEx As TaskCanceledException
                ' Don't care - catch a cancellation request
                Debug.Print(tcEx.Message)
            Catch wEx As WebException
                ' Internet connection failed? Internal server error? See what to do
                Debug.Print(wEx.Message)
            End Try
        Loop
    End Function

    Public Async Function StopDownload() As Task
        Try
            cts.Cancel()
            client?.CancelPendingRequests()
            Await Task.Delay(interval)
        Finally
            client?.Dispose()
            cts?.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposed AndAlso disposing Then
            client?.Dispose()
            client = Nothing
        End If
        disposed = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your listbox and richtextbox accesses must run on the UI thread.  The easiest way to do it is like this.

```
                                     Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                                   ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                                                   ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Split(clientdecode, vbLf))
                                                   RichTextBox1.SelectionStart() = RichTextBox1.TextLength
                                                   RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                                               End Sub)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. It seems to work but I want to double check I made it right. 
Using the code I posted,  I delete listbox and richtextbox accesses, and after the line "Dim Client code as string" I have to insert the code you just wrote. 
Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mattia - right.  I rearranged your access to the richtextbox and listbox so you shouldn't have any other accesses other than in the code I posted.  Glad it helped.